# How to store Post array into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is my  HTML Dynamic Form. You can add "n" Rows, to add multiple products.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control cantClass" name="n_cantidad[]"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control autocompletModelo" id="modelo1" name="n_modelo[]"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control serieClass" name="n_serie[]"/>
<textarea readonly class="form-control descrClass" id ="descripcion1" rows="2" name="n_descripcion[]"/></textarea>
```

Then im using serialize() in my jQuery Functions.

In PHP, I have the POST variables (Arrays):

```
$value_cantidad = ($_POST['n_cantidad']);
$value_modelo = ($_POST['n_modelo']);
$value_serie = ($_POST['n_serie']);
$value_descripcion = ($_POST['n_descripcion']);
```

I'm able to do and INSERT into MYSQL like this and it works :

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $bd_base . '.'.$bd_table.' (cantidad, modelo, serie, descripcion) VALUES ("' . $v_cantidad[0] . '", "' . $v_modelo[0] . '", "' . $v_serie[0] . '", "' . $v_descripcion[0] . '")';
```

How can Insert into MySQL table multiple rows? For example

```
 $sql = INSERT ....var [0] var [0] var [0] var [0]
 $sql = INSERT ....var [1] var [1] var [1] var [1]
```

Comment: Do a for-loop on any array, check input or filter and insert :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of php you are using, you can use "mysql" or "mysqli".

Mysqli is preferred if you use a recent php version.

A regular insert request would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

In php, you can store the request in a string:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES ($val[0], $val[1], $val[2],...);"
```

then execute it using mysqli.

Here is a sample mysqli request taken from w3school:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

If this website is to be open to the public, I would also suggest you to filter the input using a prepared query to prevent sql injections:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp